# Form Validation doesn't validate for Password

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I can't see what's wrong. When I try to validate email it works fine, but it doesn't check for the password at all! It's literally the simplest a program can get.

````
    function validateForm() {
        var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
        var password = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;

        if (email == "") {
            alert("Email must be filled out");
            document.getElementById("emailE").innerHTML = "<font color=\"red\"> Pls fill in email.</font>";
            return false;
        }

        else if (password == "" && password.length > 8) {
            alert("Password must be filled out");
            document.getElementById("passwordE").innerHTML = "<font color=\"red\"> Pls fill in password and it should be greater than 8 chars.</font>";
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>School Form</h1>

    <form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php"
        onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        <table cellspacing="10">
            <tr>
                <th>Email:</th>
                <th><input type="email" name="email"></th>
                <th><span id="emailE"></span></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Password:</th>
                <th><input type="password" name="password"></th>
                <th><span id="passwordE"></span></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: How can the password be `" " and > 8`? Also if the email throws an error, you wont ever get to the password because its wrapped in an `else-if`. Also you're `returning false` in your `if` and `else-if`

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the email and not password because once the first `if` statement is true it will not go to the `else if` of the same block so use them in different blocks of `if else` statement or use both of them in one `if` statement

secondly you are checking for the length of password is more than 8 and its value is  `''` so this is impossible to have.

Here are some suggestions

1. Font tag is depreciated a long ago so don't use this

Comment: Oops sorry, i didn't saw your comment.